# Java: How to retrieve all documents from specific bucket of couchbase server?

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-view, java-client

I am trying to retrieve all documents from my local couchbase server.
    I have created one bucket as named "student" but it just show opened bucket and give build successful message nothing happen beyond that,i am expecting list of all documents.

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create();
        Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("student");
        N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple("SELECT * FROM `student`"));

        for (N1qlQueryRow row : result) {
            String Name = row.value().getString("name");
            System.out.println(Name);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just sounds like you want to retrieve all documents from buckets created
    on local server
    You can do one thing  refer [link](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/n1ql/n1ql-intro/cbq.html#concept_s5k_qtx_1t) it might be helpful for you
    after following all steps just run following command on terminal

```
create primary index on `beer-sample`;
```

Comment: @prashantpatil yes just follow link and all steps and then run the command one in answer it will work

Comment: @prashantpatil and please give name of bucket from which you want to fetch data replacing "beer-sample" word

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore.